# How do I run a terminate command on JFrame exit?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I know the basics behind trying to write code that terminates a thread, but I've run into a bit of a problem.

I've got a JButton in a JFrame GUI that launches the simulation I'm trying to animate. It is called in the ActionPerformed code of the JButton by

```
new AnswerWorker().execute();
```

The AnswerWorker class, in turn, extends SwingWorker so that the animation frame can be drawn while the GUI is still active.

```
public class AnswerWorker extends SwingWorker<String, Integer> {
    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception
    {
        Threading threading = new Threading();
    return null;
    }
protected void done()
{
try {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(InputGUI.this, AMEC.unsuccesfulpercentage + "% of iterations had trucks that had to sleep over");
    AMEC.unsuccesfulpercentage = 0;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

To create a way of stopping the simulation thread, I created the class Threading, that calls the function that runs the simulation.

```
public class Threading extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    try {
        AMEC.runsimulation();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InputGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InputGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        }
    return;
    }
}
```

Now, in the runsimulation() function, I initialize a JFrame, and I want to terminate the thread running the simulation if the JFrame is closed by clicking on its close button. How do I do this?

EDIT: all of the above code is called in a file InputGUI.java that contains all my GUI elements. The runsimulation function is in my main project file, AMEC.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the dispose() method on the JFrame to include a call to stop the thread

```
@Override
dispose(){
   stopThread();
   super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: At dispose() { it tells me "Invalid declaration; return type required". Any ideas?

Comment: I tried that, but it now claims you can't override dispose in awt.Window, as it says "attempting to assign weaker access privileges, was public"

Comment: public void dispose() ;D

Comment: After that on the constructor you need to call the method JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)

Comment: Ah thanks! Lastly, it says "cannot find symbol: method stopThread". How do I reference the correct thread and terminate it?

Comment: you have to create that method, I just put it there as an example

Comment: @Martin, don't override the dispose() method. Use a WindowListener. The listener was designed to handle situations like this. It is  preferable to use the existing API instead of overriding a method like this.

Comment: @camickr I would agree if it were a complicated override, this is just as safe and less complex (relatively)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I run a terminate command on JFrame exit?

- add [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) to JFrame, from `windowClosing` event you have to call `JFrame.setVisible(false)` and then to call `SwingWorker`
- after `SwingWorker` ended to terminate current JVM, to show a `JOptionPane` in the case that  any exception raised, or to show JFrame again back to screen, required to change `DefaultCloseOperation, to HIDE_ON_CLOSE`

Comment: How do I call SwingWorker? Do I call the instance InputGUI.AnswerWorker, or do I reference SwingWorker directly? And what is  the syntax for terminating or interrupting that thread?

Comment: @Martin  This is a Q&A site, where you seem to need a tutor.  Voting to close as 'too broad'.